# Teamcity doesn't show jmeter tests results after the first test failure

Tags: jmeter, continuous-integration, automated-tests, teamcity, performance-testing

When I run build on teamcity, it stops showing tests after the first failure, despite of Jmeter log file contains all tests results.

I need to see on tests tab results of all tests.

As you can see from screenshots below, the result that I have in log file doesn't match the result, that I have on tests tab. If I uncheck Assertions checkbox in build features, it still shows only 12 tests instead of 332.
Is there an any way I can fix this?

**Jmeter log file:**

[image]

**Teamcity tests tab:**

[image]

**Teacity settings:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out, where was the problem: I had to delete jmeter.log and jmeter_logfile.jtl.
Build agent recreated these files and everything started to work as needed.